# Highcharts (rCharts) onclick tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I'm trying to reproduce this jsfiddle where the tooltip only appears when the point is clicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/2/

This is my "translation" into rCharts:

```
a <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()

a$xAxis(categories = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                       "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

a$tooltip(valueSuffix = " ºC", 
          enabled = F)

a$chart(list(events = list(load = "#! function()
                                    this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip) !#")))                    

a$plotOptions(events = list(click = "#! function(evt)
                                      this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt) !#",
                            mouseOut = "#! function() 
                                         this.chart.myTooltip.hide() !#"))

a$series(list(
  list(name = "Tokyo",
       data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 
                25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6))))

a
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the JS part which is not being understood by rCharts. Any ideas? Help?

Thanks,

Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. `a$chart(list(events =` should be `a$chart(events =` the same structure as in `a$xAxis(categories =`
2. `a$plotOptions(events =` needs to be `a$plotOptions(series = list(events =` or you could use another series type name instead of **series**, but **series** works for all series types.
3. All three functions must use `{` and `}` for body of each function.

Working code:

```
a <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()

a$xAxis(categories = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                       "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
))

a$tooltip(valueSuffix = " ºC", 
          enabled = F
)

a$chart(events = list(load = "#! function() { 
          this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip); 
       } !#"
))

a$plotOptions(series = list(events = list(click = "#! function(evt) {
          this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
       } !#",
       mouseOut = "#! function() {
          this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
       } !#"
)))

a$series(list(list(name = "Tokyo",
                   data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 
                           25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)
)))

a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, what would be the trick to print the degree symbol º properly?

Comment: @Carlos You are welcome. You could set tooltip as: `a$tooltip(valueSuffix = " &deg;C", 
          enabled = F,
          useHTML = T
)`